# Flutter amplify race condition with configuration

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I'm facing a race condition on flutter amplify.
Following the documentation i added the config method into the initState.

```
Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {   
AmplifyAuthCognito authPlugin = AmplifyAuthCognito();   
await Amplify.addPlugins([authPlugin]);   try {
    await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);   
} on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
        print(
            "Tried to reconfigure Amplify; this can occur when your app restarts on Android.");   } }
```

This is where is called:

```
   @override   initState() {
    _configureAmplify();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();   }
```

One of the screen is trying to fetch the auth token in his init state and i keep getting this flow:

I/flutter ( 6284): Configuring amplify
I/flutter ( 6284): Fetching token
I/flutter ( 6284): Auth plugin has not been added to Amplify

The configuration is not finished when the initstate of the screen tries to fetch the auth token.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

**WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await configureAmplify();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag to your class

```
bool _isAmplifyConfigured = false; 
late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<MyClass>> _subscription;
```

Then modify your code

```
if (!_isAmplifyConfigured) { Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {  AmplifyAuthCognito authPlugin = AmplifyAuthCognito();    await Amplify.addPlugins([authPlugin]);   try {
    await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);    } on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
        print(
            "Tried to reconfigure Amplify; this can occur when your app restarts on Android.");   } } }
```

and add listener to your class

```
_subscription = Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(MyClass.classType)
      .listen((QuerySnapshot<Todo> snapshot) {
    setState(() {
      if (_isLoading) _isLoading = false;
      _todos = snapshot.items;
    });
  });
```